# Can people read server side node.js?

Tags: node.js

I have code that I don't necessarily want other people seeing (For copyright purposes). can other people read my server side code if it is written in node.js and run from a server I own?

Comment: That depends entirely on how you've configured your web server. Generally speaking, no, but it's certainly not difficult to put your scripts in a directory to which the web server has access, and you might do that without knowing.

Comment: For security, I specifically allow individual files to be accessed, like index.html (this is a white-list system), does that mean I can have main.js in the same folder as index.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, yet very relevant question, thank you!

Generally client-side javascript code is visible to the client, as it is embedded in the HTML page, and it is done with the knowledge of the code owner, without much copyright issues - as they are mainly used as helper functions to render the page in an efficient and powerful manner.

The server-side javascript code which is run in the server (for example in Node platform), you don't have any reason to push those code which contain confidential business logic to the client - instead, you perform the server side activities and build a response to the client, in the form of an HTML page, optionally embedding java-script code which will enrich the page rendition.

So the bottom line is that only the one which is written to the client in response to the request, will be visible outside.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

No. As long as the files themselves are not served to the user by the webserver, the code cannot be read unless they gain access to your server.